# iframe in center of div

Tags: javascript, html

I want that my iframe is in the center of my div box right now, but I want it that that iframe goes in the center hope you guys can help me that I can that iframe in the middle of that white box.

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/fvuuqq.png]

game1.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Racegame</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/initresize.js" ></script>


        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-noscript.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body> 

    <script>
     function showhide()
     {
           var div = document.getElementById("codebox");
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
     }
  </script>
  <script>
  function resizeanshow()
  {
  showhide();

  }
  </script>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <nav id="nav">
        <a href="index.html#work" class="icon fa fa-arrow-circle-left"style=color:red><span>Terug</span></a>
      </nav>
      <div id="main">
        <article id="work" class="panel">
          <header><h2></h2></header>
          <p></p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="4u">
               <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="games/racegame/foto/fotozonder.PNG" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="8u">
               <header>
                  <h1><strong>Racegame</strong></h1>
               </header>
               <p>Spel gemaakt in unity.<br> probeer zo snel mogelijk de finish te halen.</p>
            </div>
            <p>Probeer zo snel mogelijk de finish te halen. Op het circuit heb je een paar obstakels.Deze kan je ontwijken. door de highscores kan je tegen je vrienden racen.De code die gebruikt is kunt u onderaan de pagina vinden.</p>
            <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
                <source src="games/racegame/filmpje/racegamefilmpje.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
            <div>
                Controls<br>
                WASD = sturen<br>
                Spatiebalk = remmen
            </div>
            <iframe src="https://c94f7e475c7659ee4ccbf6cdc7964f3cb25bec69.googledrive.com/host/0BzR73x5dCHdZenhLMVUtUEJLSlE/racegame.html" width="960" height="650" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
        </div>
        <button  id="bodyresize">Bekijk hier de code voor de auto</button>
        <div id="codebox" style="display:none">
          <p><!-- //code hier//code hier --></p>
        </div>
      </article>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
    <ul class="copyright">
        <li>&copy; Sander Gouman All rights reserved. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sander.gouman" class="icon fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></a><a href="" class="icon fa-youtube-square fa-2x"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

initresize.js

```
/*
    Astral by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
*/
 function showhide()
     {
           var div = document.getElementById("codebox");
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
     }

(function($) {
    /* Settings */
     var settings = {

            // Speed to resize panel.
                resizeSpeed: 600,

            // Speed to fade in/out.
                fadeSpeed: 300,

            // Size factor.
                sizeFactor: 11.5,       

            // Minimum point size.
                sizeMin: 15,            

            // Maximum point size.
                sizeMax: 15         

        };

    /* skel  */
       skel.init({
            reset: 'full',
            pollOnce: true,
            breakpoints: {
                'global':   { range: '*', href: 'css/style.css' },
                'desktop':  { range: '737-', href: 'css/style-desktop.css', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 25 }, viewport: { width: 1080, scalable: false } },
                'mobile':   { range: '-736', href: 'css/style-mobile.css', containers: '100%!', grid: { collapse: true, gutters: 15 }, viewport: { scalable: false } }
            }
        });

    /* Main */
    var $window = $(window);

        $window.on('load', function() {

            var $body = $('body'),
                $main = $('#main'),
                $panels = $main.find('.panel'),
                $hbw = $('html,body,window'),
                $footer = $('#footer'),
                $wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
                $nav = $('#nav'), $nav_links = $nav.find('a'),
                $jumplinks = $('.jumplink'),
                $form = $('form'),
                panels = [],
                activePanelId = null,
                firstPanelId = null,
                isLocked = false,
                hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

            if (skel.vars.isTouch) {
                settings.fadeSpeed = 0;
                settings.resizeSpeed = 0;
                $nav_links.find('span').remove();
            }

            if (skel.isActive('desktop')) {

                // Body.
                    $body._resize = function() {
                        var factor = ($window.width() * $window.height()) / (1440 * 900);
                        $body.css('font-size', Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor * settings.sizeFactor), settings.sizeMin), settings.sizeMax) + 'pt');
                        $main.height(panels[activePanelId].outerHeight());
                        $body._reposition();
                    };

                    $body._reposition = function() {
                        if (skel.vars.isTouch && (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180))
                            $wrapper.css('padding-top', Math.max((($window.height() - (panels[activePanelId].outerHeight() + $footer.outerHeight())) / 2) - $nav.height(), 30) + 'px');
                        else
                            $wrapper.css('padding-top', ((($window.height() - panels[firstPanelId].height()) / 2) - $nav.height()) + 'px');
                    };
                    ////test
                     // document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function() 

                     // document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function() 

                     document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function() 
                    {
                    showhide();
                        var factor = ($window.width() * $window.height()) / (1440 * 900);
                        $body.css('font-size', Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor * settings.sizeFactor), settings.sizeMin), settings.sizeMax) + 'pt');
                        $main.height(panels[activePanelId].outerHeight());
                        $body._reposition2();
                    };

                    $body._reposition2 = function() {
                        if (skel.vars.isTouch && (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180))
                            $wrapper.css('padding-top', Math.max((($window.height() - (panels[activePanelId].outerHeight() + $footer.outerHeight())) / 2) - $nav.height(), 30) + 'px');
                        else
                            $wrapper.css('padding-top', ((($window.height() - panels[firstPanelId].height()) / 2) - $nav.height()) + 'px');
                    };
                ////test    
                // Panels.
                $panels.each(function(i) {
                        var t = $(this), id = t.attr('id');
                        panels[id] = t;
                        if (i == 0) {
                            firstPanelId = id;
                            activePanelId = id;
                        }
                        else
                            t.hide();
                        t._activate = function(instant) {
                            // Check lock state and determine whether we're already at the target.
                                if (isLocked
                                ||  activePanelId == id)
                                    return false;

                            // Lock.
                                isLocked = true;

                            // Change nav link (if it exists).
                                $nav_links.removeClass('active');
                                $nav_links.filter('[href="#' + id + '"]').addClass('active');

                            // Change hash.
                                if (i == 0)
                                    window.location.hash = '#';
                                else
                                    window.location.hash = '#' + id;

                            // Add bottom padding.
                                var x = parseInt($wrapper.css('padding-top')) +
                                        panels[id].outerHeight() +
                                        $nav.outerHeight() +
                                        $footer.outerHeight();

                                if (x > $window.height())
                                    $wrapper.addClass('tall');
                                else
                                    $wrapper.removeClass('tall');

                            // Fade out active panel.
                                $footer.fadeTo(settings.fadeSpeed, 0.0001);
                                panels[activePanelId].fadeOut(instant ? 0 : settings.fadeSpeed, function() {

                                    // Set new active.
                                        activePanelId = id;

                                        // Force scroll to top.
                                            $hbw.animate({
                                                scrollTop: 0
                                            }, settings.resizeSpeed, 'swing');

                                        // Reposition.
                                            $body._reposition();

                                        // Resize main to height of new panel.
                                            $main.animate({
                                                height: panels[activePanelId].outerHeight()
                                            }, instant ? 0 : settings.resizeSpeed, 'swing', function() {

                                                // Fade in new active panel.
                                                    $footer.fadeTo(instant ? 0 : settings.fadeSpeed, 1.0);
                                                    panels[activePanelId].fadeIn(instant ? 0 : settings.fadeSpeed, function() {

                                                        // Unlock.
                                                            isLocked = false;
                                                    });
                                            });
                                });
                        };

                    });

                // Nav + Jumplinks.
                    $nav_links.add($jumplinks).click(function(e) {
                        var t = $(this), href = t.attr('href'), id;

                        if (href.substring(0,1) == '#') {

                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();

                            id = href.substring(1);

                            if (id in panels)
                                panels[id]._activate();
                        }

                    });

                // Window.
                    $window
                        .resize(function() {

                            if (!isLocked)
                                $body._resize();

                        });

                    if (skel.vars.IEVersion < 9)
                        $window
                            .on('resize', function() {
                                $wrapper.css('min-height', $window.height());
                            });

                // Forms (IE<10).
                    if ($form.length > 0) {

                        if (skel.vars.IEVersion < 10) {
                            $.fn.n33_formerize=function(){var _fakes=new Array(),_form = $(this);_form.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.val() == '' || e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } }).blur(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) return; if (e.val() == '') { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } }).focus(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) return; if (e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(''); } }); _form.find('input[type=password]').each(function() { var e = $(this); var x = $($('<div>').append(e.clone()).remove().html().replace(/type="password"/i, 'type="text"').replace(/type=password/i, 'type=text')); if (e.attr('id') != '') x.attr('id', e.attr('id') + '_fakeformerizefield'); if (e.attr('name') != '') x.attr('name', e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield'); x.addClass('formerize-placeholder').val(x.attr('placeholder')).insertAfter(e); if (e.val() == '') e.hide(); else x.hide(); e.blur(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var e = $(this); var x = e.parent().find('input[name=' + e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield]'); if (e.val() == '') { e.hide(); x.show(); } }); x.focus(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var x = $(this); var e = x.parent().find('input[name=' + x.attr('name').replace('_fakeformerizefield', '') + ']'); x.hide(); e.show().focus(); }); x.keypress(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); x.val(''); }); });  _form.submit(function() { $(this).find('input[type=text],input[type=password],textarea').each(function(event) { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) e.attr('name', ''); if (e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(''); } }); }).bind("reset", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); $(this).find('select').val($('option:first').val()); $(this).find('input,textarea').each(function() { var e = $(this); var x; e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); switch (this.type) { case 'submit': case 'reset': break; case 'password': e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); x = e.parent().find('input[name=' + e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield]'); if (e.val() == '') { e.hide(); x.show(); } else { e.show(); x.hide(); } break; case 'checkbox': case 'radio': e.attr('checked', e.attr('defaultValue')); break; case 'text': case 'textarea': e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); if (e.val() == '') { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } break; default: e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); break; } }); window.setTimeout(function() { for (x in _fakes) _fakes[x].trigger('formerize_sync'); }, 10); }); return _form; };
                            $form.n33_formerize();
                        }

                    }

                // CSS polyfills (IE<9).
                    if (skel.vars.IEVersion < 9)
                        $(':last-child').addClass('last-child');

                // Init.
                    $window
                        .trigger('resize');

                    if (hash && hash in panels)
                        panels[hash]._activate(true);

                    $wrapper.fadeTo(400, 1.0);

            }

        });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! this is a big lot of code to center `<iframe>` in a `<div>` You might just show the relevant code to reproduce "iframe center" problem

Comment: According to your screenshot, your iframe seems to be wider than the surrounding container. The height and width of the iframe are set by html attributes right in your html:

`<iframe src="https://c94f7e475c7659ee4ccbf6cdc7964f3cb25bec69.googledrive.com/host/0BzR73x5dCHdZenhLMVUtUEJLSlE/racegame.html" width="960" height="650" scrolling="no" ></iframe>`

Can you please also post the CSS?

The css code to center a block level element is usually `margin: 0 auto;`, but the surrounding container may also have padding, in which case you'd have to go a different path.

Comment: Can you post also the CSS part?

Comment: here is my style.css

http://pastebin.com/2JMiCJYF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to drop about 150px from your width, like so:

```
<iframe src="https://c94f7e475c7659ee4ccbf6cdc7964f3cb25bec69.googledrive.com/host/0BzR7‌​3x5dCHdZenhLMVUtUEJLSlE/racegame.html" width="810" height="650" scrolling="no" >
```

It might be centered at this point, but if it isn't just apply `margin: 0 auto;` to the style.

Edit:

If for some reson you want to ignore the padding on the left, you could apply `margin-left: -75px`

Note: these numbers are estimates based on the image you provided.

Edit 2:

Change the width of the panel class from 45em to 51.5em, disregard previous changes. Also change the #wrapper width from 45em to 51.5em

Comment: hello

the problem is that  the iframe  is a unity game and i cant make that smaller so the widhth should be 960

Comment: because then then my game is cut off a bit

Comment: Then you need to make the container larger, or remove the left side padding/margin. If you put your code in a jsfiddle.net, I could be of more assistance.

Comment: didnt use jsiffle before

So i think you mean this? 

http://jsfiddle.net/03reaLfL/

Keep in mind there are 2 files in css devided bij //////////// lines

Comment: you can also download the full site here:
https://mega.co.nz/#!74VSRLQY!ORruQkF0DPqOB-9zrfj-9PwoMAia9t4wjvpG66ImDgQ

the problem is in game1.html

Comment: View my second edit entitled "Edit 2", that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With 100% for both width and height, your iframe should fill the whole div content. Now if you add padding around, be sure to set `box-sizing: border-box` on your iframe so the padding is not added to the dimensions, but part of it. See example below.

If your case is different please  create a snippet (or jsfiddle) that only shows your issue, we don't want your whole website code in a jsfiddle.

```css
body { background: #ddd; }

.container {
    background: orange;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 20px;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
</div>
```